# Trying to make tables in mono develop

Tags: mono

I just started using monodevelop and I am having a hard time to design the forms. I have understood the concept of widgets inside containes. I am trying to get a Table which is inside a scroll view. The Table should have 3 columns and I should be able to set the column names.

I have looked at some documentation by mono develop which shows how to use the Node View to do the same but I haven't been able to figure out why is it coming in a new window and how to get it on my first screen itself.Also is there any way I can drag and drop to the form to make my columns and table header? I have attached the code :

```
using System;
using Gtk;
namespace ImageCompressionTool
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init ();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
            win.Show ();
            Application.Run ();

            Gtk.Application.Init ();
            NodeViewExample win1 = new NodeViewExample ();
            win1.Show ();
            Gtk.Application.Run ();

        }

    }
    public class MyTreeNode : Gtk.TreeNode {

        string song_title;

        public MyTreeNode (string artist, string song_title)
        {
            Artist = artist;
            this.song_title = song_title;
        }

        [Gtk.TreeNodeValue (Column=0)]
        public string Artist;

        [Gtk.TreeNodeValue (Column=1)]
        public string SongTitle {get { return song_title; } }

    }

    public class NodeViewExample : Gtk.Window {
        Gtk.NodeStore store;
        Gtk.NodeStore Store {
            get {
                if (store == null) {
                    store = new Gtk.NodeStore (typeof (MyTreeNode));
                    store.AddNode (new MyTreeNode ("The Beatles", "Yesterday"));
                    store.AddNode (new MyTreeNode ("Peter Gabriel", "In Your Eyes"));
                    store.AddNode (new MyTreeNode ("Rush", "Fly By Night"));
                }
                return store;
            }
        }

        public NodeViewExample () : base ("NodeView")
        {
            SetSizeRequest (200,150);

            // Create our TreeView and add it as our child widget
            Gtk.NodeView view = new Gtk.NodeView (Store);
            Add (view);

            // Create a column with title Artist and bind its renderer to model column 0
            view.AppendColumn ("Artist", new Gtk.CellRendererText (), "text", 0);

            // Create a column with title 'Song Title' and bind its renderer to model column 1
            view.AppendColumn ("Song Title", new Gtk.CellRendererText (), "text", 1);
            view.ShowAll ();
        }

    }


}
```

Kindly help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Please supply the code you've attempted and the results you got.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The above code shows 2 windows, first it launches the main window with my GUI and when I try to close it, it pops up a new window with my table.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want your NodeView window to be displayed then remove the code that is showing the MainWindow. Your Main method is currently showing two windows. If you just want it to show your NodeViewExample window then it should look like:

```
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Gtk.Application.Init ();
        NodeViewExample win1 = new NodeViewExample ();
        win1.Show ();
        Gtk.Application.Run ();
    }
```

You cannot drag and drop columns into a Gtk.NodeView or Gtk.TreeView into the designer.